# Searching multiple tables in Postgres and Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, full-text-search

I use [PostgreSQL's full text search](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/textsearch.html) capabilities, which works fine. All the relevant columns are indexed so it's nice and speedy:

```
  def self.text_search(query)
    if (query.present?)
      # search(query)
      where(
          "to_tsvector('english', title) @@ plainto_tsquery(:q)",
          q: query
      )
    else
      scoped
    end
  end
```

But now I also want to search through related abbreviations:

```
def self.text_search(query)
    if (query.present?)
      # search(query)
      includes(:abbreviations).where(
          "to_tsvector('english', articles.title) @@ plainto_tsquery(:q)"+
          " or to_tsvector('english', abbreviations.abbreviation) @@ plainto_tsquery(:q)",
          q: query
      )
    else
      scoped
    end
  end
```

This works, but now my queries take 2.5+ seconds! How do I remedy this? I was thinking that maybe this is a Rails inefficiency, so I could best perform raw SQL. But how do I do that and still get back a ActiveRecord relation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I did as a workaround, added a str_* column to my main table, and update this column when an element is saved, and then search over that column:

```
  before_validation(on: :create) do
    self.str_abbreviations = join_abbreviations()
    ... etc ...
    true
  end
```